# Why does Flash Builder Premium launch as Standard version when I switch workspace?

Tags: apache-flex, mxml, flash-builder

I think my title explains my problem quite clearly.

When I change my workspace I copy my .settings folder to the new .metadata folder:

.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/

This is so that I can transfer my font and syntax colouring preferences (preferences export doesn't seem to work).

When I relaunch the workspace Flash Builder launches as Standard on the splash screen and Premium features are disabled.

The problem is obviously related to my .settings folder thought I'm not sure exactly what I need to change to fix this.

Any suggestions gratefully received!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but one never knows :)

You should let eclipse manually create the workspace for you by going to **File -> Switch Workspace -> Other...** and selecting an empty folder, check the "workbench layout" check box and click OK.

Once your new workspace created, you can start messing with it and copy settings there.

That being said, export/import preferences should work, which eclipse do you use?
FYI, I use **Eclipse IDE for Java Developers 3.7** and each time I reinstall it, I import my preferences.